# How to set Zabbix Log Monitor to start from where it left last time

Tags: logging, server, monitoring, zabbix

Curretnly I'm using Zabbix to monitor one of my web servers and one of the monitoring tasks is to monitor the catalina log file to see if there is any error occured. 
I've set up the Zabbix Agent and enabled active checks. It will notify me when there are lines matching "ERROR" in the log file catalina.log. 
 However, the issue is whenever there is a new error line added, Zabbix will send me all the lines containing the word "ERROR" instead of just the new lines with errors. I dont want this because I have already been notified for those previous "ERROR"s.

The key for log monitoring in Zabbix is

```
log[file,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>,<output>]
```

I set it as

```
log[/root/test/test2.log, "ERROR"]
```

I also tried to set it as

```
log[/root/test/test2.log, "ERROR",,,skip,]
```

But it all wont work. It keeps spamming with all the existing errors. Hence, I want to ask yall if it is the default way of log monitoring or there is some way to achieve what I desire. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `skip` should be the default and the agent should not re-read the whole file. It might depend on the agent version - if it is an older agent, consider upgrading to Zabbix 3.0, as [this feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-444) could have solved the problem for you.

If that already is the latest 3.0 Zabbix agent, the application could be doing something unexpected like updating the logfile timestamp without adding any content. In that case you would have to narrow it down to the exact circumstances that make the agent re-read the file.

Comment: I did not set up the log timestamp format though. My log file was only a dummy test log file which also does not contain any timestamp on each line. So are you suggesting that this might be the issue of causing that problem?

Comment: No, log timestamp format is for parsing the log lines itself - the problem is likely related to the timestamp of the whole logfile.